# Creating a slicer for pivot table to select multiple values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a dataset from excel which I created a pivot table for like below:

[image: Sample Data]

So I created a pivot table based on the data to sum the Check per Name from the raw data. I want to use Time as a slicer here - but as you can see, if I want to select the last 12 weeks of data, I will need to filter to both Last 4 Weeks and 5-12 Weeks. If I want to select all the time ranges, I will need to check all the items within the slicer.

Just wondering if there is a way for me to create a slicer, with options:

1. Last 4 Weeks (If I click this I will filter my data with Time = Last 4 Weeks
2. Last 12 Weeks(If I click this I will filter my data with Time = Last 4 Weeks **and** Time = 5-12 Weeks)
3. All (If I click this I will select every time value - basically a select all.)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to create your own "slicer" of shapes and assign macros to each shape (using a smart table as an example):

Macros must be placed in the sheet module.

```
Sub w4()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "=Last 4 Weeks"
End Sub

Sub w5()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "=5-12 Weeks"
End Sub

Sub w12()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "=5-12 Weeks", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Last 4 Weeks"
End Sub

Sub w13()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "=13-20 Weeks"
End Sub

Sub FReset()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the task correctly, then ordinary slices implement this functionality. Selecting several filter values: Ctrl + Left Mouse Button (or the switch in the slice header with check marks). Displaying all records means removing the filter - a funnel icon with a red cross in the slice header. The screenshot shows an example based on a smart table:
[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes, the default slicer could already do the work. However, some potential users of this report may not understand this....Instead of selecting both Last 4 Weeks and 5-12 Weeks in order to select the "last 12 weeks" data, they want a "last 12 weeks" option within the slicer for them to one-click.

Comment: One solution would be to create an auxiliary Time2 field in the range that the pivot table is built on, with a formula like [= IF (OR (B2 = "Last 4 Weeks", B2 = "5-12 Weeks"), "last 12 weeks", " 13-20 Weeks ")], which returns "Last 4 Weeks" and "5-12 Weeks" for the values in the Time field, the result "last 12 weeks", and creates a second slice on the Time2 field. In this case, the auxiliary field may not be displayed in the pivot table.